# How do I add a form to the panel properly

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I designed a side panel and when I press the buttons, the form inside the panel on the right changes. However, the components in the forms I designed appear in the wrong places. Some are not visible because they are left outside.

I upload some photos. [Design Screen](https://ibb.co/T1NtXN4) and
[at Runtime](https://ibb.co/868CkFQ)

Where am i doing wrong ? Panel Size and form size are same.

**UPDATE**:

I created usercontrol instead of form. However, nothing has changed. For example, when I put two labels side by side with 5 px between them in the design, it seems to have much more spacing if I run it. Or the labels I placed at the far right or at the bottom do not appear at runtime.

```
            TelemetriUI telemetriUI = new TelemetriUI();


            telemetriUI.TopLevel = false;
            

            telemetriUI.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            telemetriUI.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
          
            this.mainPanel.Controls.Add(telemetriUI);
            this.mainPanel.Tag = telemetriUI;
            telemetriUI.BringToFront();
            telemetriUI.Show();
```

Comment: Build UserControls instead of Forms. An UserControl also has its Designer -- What kind of Controls does this Form contain? Do you have non-standard Controls? -- *Panel size and Form size are same* doesn't mean much, since you haven't specified which one is the largest, by design (e.g., if the Form's design size is larger than the Panel, but it's sized as the Panel at run-time, then...)

Comment: @Jimi Thank you I will try UserControls instead of Forms. All of them are standard things like label and button.

Comment: @Jimi problem not solved unfortunately. I upload some photos. This is from design screen [link](https://ibb.co/T1NtXN4) This photo is at runtime [link](https://ibb.co/868CkFQ)

Comment: What are we looking at here? If you have tried something else, post that code (as part of the question, not in comments). An image doesn't explain what you have actually done (e.g., what those *characters* represent, what Controls you added to what Container and based on what criteria)

Comment: @Jimi Sorry for that. I added UserControl to the panel. I designed UserControl with drag and drop without code. I deliberately superimposed the word "USER CONTROL TEST" in the design. However, as you can see in the photo, they separate from each other when I run the program. Similarly, if I put the label at the bottom or the right, they do not appear in the panel when I run the program.

Comment: But, did you specify the size and location of these Controls while you were adding them to the Container? In any case, as mentioned, if you have written some other code, you need to post that code. We're dealing with code here

Comment: Forgot to mention: since usually Controls inherit their Font settings from their Parent, you may have different settings in this department. When a Container if configured with a larger Font than the Controls it's hosting, when you add a Control (or UserControl), this child Control inherits the Font from the new Parent, thus it adapts and auto-sizes its Content, if it's also designed to scale to Font instead of DPI